# Using tidyr pivot_wider warning values not uniquely identified

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, spread

I have a df called **dfmelt** that I want to pivot to wide format. It has five columns: *study_id* and *redcap_event_name* are ID columns, with *variable* and *value* being key-value pairs and *num* being a numeric (1,2,...n) grouped by *study_id* and *redcap_event_name* that I want suffixed to the *variable* column header in the wide dataframe. Below is a snippet:

| study_id | redcap_event_name | variable | value | num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHLA_0014 | csf_shunt_infectio_arm_1 | micro_sample_dt | 7/22/21 | 1 |
| CHLA_0014 | csf_shunt_infectio_arm_1 | micro_sample_dt | 7/22/21 | 2 |
| CHLA_0014 | csf_shunt_infectio_arm_1 | micro_sample_dt | 7/22/21 | 3 |
| CHLA_0014 | csf_shunt_infectio_arm_1 | micro_sample_time | 18:19 | 1 |
| CHLA_0014 | csf_shunt_infectio_arm_1 | micro_sample_time | 18:38 | 2 |
| CHLA_0014 | csf_shunt_infectio_arm_1 | micro_sample_time | 18:38 | 3 |
| CHLA_0067 | initial_shunt_plac_arm_1 | micro_culture_source | 1 | 1 |
| CHLA_0067 | initial_shunt_plac_arm_1 | micro_culture_source | 1 | 2 |
| CHLA_0067 | initial_shunt_plac_arm_1 | micro_culture_source | 1 | 3 |

I attempted pivot_wider with these arguments to get {variable}{num} as the column headers with no separator.

```
pivot_wider(dfmelt, id_cols = c(1:2), names_from = c(variable), values_from = c(value), names_glue = "{variable}{num}")
```

I received this error message: Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.

This is the target format of above:

| study_id | redcap_event_name | micro_sample_dt1 | micro_sample_time1 | micro_culture_source1 | micro_sample_dt2 | micro_sample_time2 | micro_culture_source2 | micro_sample_dt3 | micro_sample_time3 | micro_culture_source3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHLA_0014 | csf_shunt_infectio_arm_1 | 7/22/21 | 18:19 | 1 | 0 | 7/22/21 | 18:38 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| CHLA_0067 | initial_shunt_plac_arm_1 |  |  | 1 |  |  | 1 |  |  | 1 |

Comment: Can you clarify what the exact desired output for this sample input is so we can test and verify possible solutions?